# deleting multiple numbered folders in the terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I have directories numbered from 0-1000, for example. I want to delete the directories within the range 400-699, for example, and all their contents on the terminal. Is there a way to do this without me having to do rm -rf XXX where XXX is the directory number?

I have seen this post [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529270/how-can-i-delete-numbered-files-in-a-given-range) but the numbering system we have is a bit different.

Comment: How are the folders numbered?

Comment: They are numbered like this: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 1000

Comment: Yes but how are the full names, the pattern? Because if the names are just 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 1000. Then the command `rm -rf {start..end}` would work.

Comment: Those are the full names, there's no strings whatsoever. Some of them have 1 digit, 2 digits, 3 digits, etc.

Comment: Also see [Standard Wildcards (globbing patterns)](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm). `rm -rf 4??` should match all the 400-series directories. Similar should apply to 500 and 600-series. But they will also match, say `40a`, `40b`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with bash loop like this:

```
for i in `seq 400 699`;
do
rm -rf $i
done
```

Please make sure every time you use `rm -rf`. It cannot be undone in Linux.

Comment: The `seq` command is not available in some versions of Bash. I had trouble with it on some OS X versions. And they were not ancient versions of OS X.

Comment: Then can you try `{400..699}` or `jot 400 699` instead?
(I haven't tried it since I'm on Ubuntu now)

Answer (score 0):

Use wildcards so you won't have to do this 300 times. Try this: `rm -rf 4* 5* 6*`

Comment: Try this then: `rm -rf 4[0-9][0-9] 5[0-9][0-9] 6[0-9][0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using Python:

```
rm -rf $(python -c "print ' '.join(str(_) for _ in range(400, 700))")
```

Be careful with `rm -rf`, before executing, verify the command.

```
echo $(python -c "print ' '.join(str(_) for _ in range(400, 700))")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that @FonyLew comment should be an answer
Easy to do it in one command:

> rm -rf {400..699}